# How to create from parcel with Kotlin @Parcelize?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcel

I'm trying to migrate parcelable model from Java to Kotlin.

My model looks like this:

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.*

@Parcelize
class SignatureAuthorityModel
    (var id: Int,
    var cloudId: Int,
    var uuid: UUID?): android.os.Parcelable
{
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean
    {
        //equals implementation
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int
    {
       //some hash implementation
    }

    override fun toString(): String
    {
       //some stringifier implementation
    }
}
```

I can call **writeToParcel** for this model, but **SignatureAuthorityModel.createFromParcel(parcel)** isn't available. Must I write it separately, or must I configure kotlin-parcelize plugin somehow? From kotlin documentation it seems that **createFromParcel** should also be generated automatically when I use **@Parcelize** annotation, and that I must write implementation in companion object Creator only if I have some advanced logic. What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this pull request](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/pull/4575/), there is a means of accessing the `CREATOR` while still using the `@Parcelize` annotation. I couldn't discover how just reading the PR or docs alone.

However, I did manage to find (in the PR) a pleasant little function that has so far been successful. I copied and pasted it easily into my project. Calling it will return a `CREATOR` from which you can then call `createFromParcel(parcel)`.

```
public inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> parcelableCreator(): Parcelable.Creator<T> =
T::class.java.getDeclaredField("CREATOR").get(null) as? Parcelable.Creator<T>
    ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Could not access CREATOR field in class ${T::class.simpleName}")
```

Here's an example of its usage in a simple test that parcels, then creates from parcel.

```
@Test
fun `UserDto parcelizes then unparcelizes`() {
    val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
    inputUserDto.writeToParcel(parcel, 0)
    parcel.setDataPosition(0)

    val userDtoFromParcel = parcelableCreator<UserDto>().createFromParcel(parcel)

    assertThat(inputUserDto).isEqualTo(userDtoFromParcel)
}
```

Here is a [link](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/pull/4575/files#diff-0e2638bf0d24236146495e7fe3294fe4903c87f6a467346d5ab86e487a651bc0) to exactly where I found the helper inline function. It may not work in every case, but so far it's been good to me.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the `CREATOR` of `Parcelable` classes annotated by `@Parcelize`, simply call `parcelableCreator` with the correct type information. See below for an example:

```kotlin
@Parcelize
data class MyParcelableClass(val someField: String): Parcelable

// getting Creator for this Parcelable
val creator = parcelableCreator<MyParcelableClass>()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `@Parcelize` annotation then you don't need to write `createFromParcel` method. Because  `@Parcelize` manages `createFromParcel` method internally.

just write your data class like below. And might be you wrong import for `Parcelable` and your class should be like below.

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
class User(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, val age: Int): Parcelable
```

Comment: Well, problem is that I cannot use this method, android studio IDE can't find it, neither do kotlin compiler. I've tried SignatureAuthorityModel.createFromParcel, SignatureAuthorityModel.Creator.createFromParcel and SignatureAuthorityModel.CREATOR.createFromParcel

Comment: As for import, if I try to write just Parcelable I get unresolved reference error with hint to chage it to android.os.Parcelable, without other variants

Comment: @CrazySage Yes, that I told you like if you are using `@Parcelize`  we don't have those methods.

Comment: Ok, but then what is there instead to create object from parcel?)

Comment: Can I know why you want to use those methods? Else you don't have to use `@Parcelize`.

Comment: I'm not sure about scenarios in existing code, because in fact I work on auto-generated interfaces for cross-language bridges, between c++ core and kotlin ui. Currently I have seen two scenarios. In one place model is parcelized, parcel is passed and model is restored from parcel in another place, I think it is for copy speed. In second scenario creator from model was passed to createTypedArrayList. If @Parcelize is only for writing parcels, but not for reading for them - I'll just restore this code from java, but it seems strange for me, that I can write but must write boilerplate for read.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue that the creator is not accessible when using @Parcelize

See this issue created 5 years ago: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19853

Following the comments there it doesn't seem like they are doing anything about it.

My personal opinion is that they probably don't bother about it because for the most common use case it's not necessary. The most common use case for Parcelable in Android development is to pass the objects from one Activity to another using `intent.putExtra()` or `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra()` and in that case the the turning into Parcel and back happens automatically.

EDIT:
hmm.. actually they mention here https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/pull/4575 that it should be available using `parcelableCreator` but I can't figure out how to use it or if it's even actually in the latest version